# Minimize rational-linear fraction function efficiently

Tags: algorithm, fractions, expression-evaluation

I need to find minimum positive value of this function, where `a_i` and `b_i` are real constants and all `s_i` are equal to plus or minus one:

[image]

I can make it in ~n*2^n operations by brute force complete search, but is it possible to do it faster? It might be a known problem, but I don't know how to google it.

Comment: Maybe [math.se] is better suited for this question.

Comment: Maybe break it up into two [LP's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)? One max, and one min?

Comment: Do you know of cases in which the maximum solution is not one in which s_i is +1 for all i such that a_i/b_i > x and is −1 for all other i, for some x? (In other words, the optimal solution would be found by sorting by a_i/b_i and then finding the optimal transition spot in the resulting list.)

Comment: What is the context of the problem? For example, it looks quite similar to the *maximization* of a ratio of weighted sums in [data envelopment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_envelopment_analysis) (DEA), so good heuristics to tackle it may be available in the literature.

Comment: I did a few brute-force tests and hypothesize the only time a solution exists where s_i is +1 for an a_i/b_i lower than some a_j/b_j with s_j = −1 is when it would make the numerator or denominator negative.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If `a_0` is positive with much larger magnitude than the remaining `a_i`, the best solution is probably `s_i==sign(b_i)` and if `b0` is positive with much larger magnitude than the remaining `b_i`, the best solution is probably to get the sum of `a_i*s_i` as close to 0 as possible (while staying positive). Neither would depend on the ratios of `a_i/b_i`.

Comment: @chtz: Take a_0 = 20, b_0 = 20, a_1 = 1, b_1 = 3. Driving a_i•s_i as close to zero as possible would give (20−1)/(20-3) = 19/17, but (20+1)/(20+3) = 21/23, which is less.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not claim that my observation was always true, but take, e.g. a0=2.001, a1=4, a2=1, a3=1, b0=1000, b1 to b3 arbitrary, but small magnitude (could be negative).